# File Saving Sometimes Fails

Tags: hard-drive

When I attempt to save files, it sometimes (randomly) fails. In Blender, I sometimes get "Version Backup Failed: File Saved With @". In Visual Studio, building sometimes fails with an error message indicating that the target file/exe cannot be overwritten.

If I wait a bit, I can save fine. It's almost as if programs are taking an abnormal amount of time to 'let go' of the files.

<strike>What could be causing this behaviour?</strike>

This seems to be caused by Windows Live Mesh monitoring my files, and locking them whenever it uploads the new versions (BAD considering the amount of times I save my files, even redundantly).

Any suggestions to work around this behaviour? Should I switch to a better service to sync my files?

Comment: does [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) show anything locking the file?

Comment: Holy smokes. Wish I knew about that tool _ages_ ago. Apparently, my file is being accessed by MOE.exe (Windows Live Mesh). My guess is that it's monitoring my files, and backs them up whenever I overwrite them... locking them while it does so. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I've never used Windows Live Mesh, but there's probably a way to temporarily stop it from syncing (there's a Pause/Resume Sync option in Dropbox) when necessary.

Comment: All we get is 'Exit'. Which means, whenever I want to turn it on/off, I'll have to quit/restart. Guess it's time to look for alternatives.

Comment: Consider whether your antivirus may also be interfering. You may be the victim of LiveMesh being delayed by an AV scanner. If that's not it, consider Box or Dropbox.

Comment: I doubt that's the problem. If it was, it would be quite funny, and a little bit sad (_Microsoft_ Security Essentials interfering with _Microsoft_ Windows Live Mesh) XD. Do the two services you mentioned not suffer from this problem?